# Meaning of asterisk following a member function

Tags: c++

I am fairly new to C++ and I am trying to decode the piece of code shown below. In particular for the `BaseSetAssoc::BlkType*` line, I am not sure what the asterisk means in this case. I would appreciate some insight.

```
BaseSetAssoc::BlkType*
NMRU::accessBlock(Addr addr, bool is_secure, Cycles &lat, int master_id)
{
    // Accesses are based on parent class, no need to do anything special
    BlkType *blk = BaseSetAssoc::accessBlock(addr, is_secure, lat, master_id);

    if (blk != NULL) {
        // move this block to head of the MRU list
        sets[blk->set].moveToHead(blk);
        DPRINTF(CacheRepl, "set %x: moving blk %x (%s) to MRU\n",
                blk->set, regenerateBlkAddr(blk->tag, blk->set),
                is_secure ? "s" : "ns");
    }

    return blk;
}
```

Comment: It means, in this case, return a pointer of the type immediately preceding it.

Comment: It means accessBlock function returns a pointer to type BaseSetAssoc::BlkType. The asterisk is not following a member function, it's part of the return type.

Comment: Really? An _exact_ duplicate?

Comment: @AndrewCheong The most helpful for a question which would be closed otherwise anyways.

Comment: Okey @Nathan found the better one :)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Yet another rushed and failed dupehammer strike...

Comment: @user2836860: * is used for mathematical operator eg int x = 5 * 4;  it is used when declaring a pointer eg: int* ptr = NULL; it is used when dereferencing a pointer: int* ptr = new int(7); cout << *ptr;

Answer (score 1):

`BlkType` isn't a member function, it's a type, possibly an enum or struct if not an inner class.

The `BaseSetAssoc::` is needed to access such "inner" types (defined within a class, *i.e.* `BaseSetAssoc`).

So `BaseSetAssoc::BlkType*` is just a `BaseSetAssoc::BlkType` pointer.

Answer (score 0):

It's not "following", it's "preceding". As the comments have said: it means that it is returning a *pointer* to `BaseSetAssoc::BlkType`, rather than a whole `BaseSetAssoc::BlkType`.

What does this mean? It means mostly that the pointer can be `NULL`, or non-existent. Before using the result of this function, it is almost *mandatory* that you check if it is `NULL` first.

Comment: And since we're talking c++ here, it should be checked against `nullptr` instead of `NULL`.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall If the version of C++ is recent enough: sure!

Comment: @JohnBurger C'mon its the current standard, under what rock you're living?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Er, there are many valid reasons to still be stuck on C++03. We're not all hobbyists on Github; some of us actually create and maintain enterprise infrastructure!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Oh wow. Under the same rock that has students studying 8-bit microprocessors. The "current standard" is ever-changing: you need to adapt your answers to what the person is asking. If I'd've answered with: "`r15` can store 64-bit results!" how would that have answered them?

Comment: _"It means mostly that the pointer can be NULL, or non-existent."_ I'd say that's tangential. The indirection is the important part.

Comment: _"Before using the result of this function, it is almost mandatory that you check if it is NULL first."_ This is also nonsense as far as general advice goes.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Whenever I define a function, it either returns an Object (OK, a POD...), a reference, or a pointer. How do I decide? If it _could_ return a `NULL`, I return a pointer. That is the _**ONLY**_ reason that I return a pointer. Otherwise I'd be asking the coder to `delete` it for me... **\*SHUDDER\***

Comment: @JohnBurger: Ehm no. You're using pointers solely on the basis of whether you _should_ be returning a `boost::optional` or not, and not using pointers at all based on any of the reasons why you should return a pointer lol. Returning a pointer certainly doesn't mandate passing ownership to the caller; for example, `std::string::c_str()`.... which is never `NULL`, and must not be `delete`d by the coder... it's a view into an existing managed buffer stored elsewhere, which is a much more useful reason to return a pointer!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Look at the code. `BlkType *blk = ...; if (blk!=NULL) {... }  return blk;` In other words, it could _easily_ return `NULL`. Thus my reason stands. And you missed my not-so-subtle \* **SHUDDER** \* - the mere _concept_ of returning a pointer to suggest that the coder should `delete` it, is anathema to me (that is, I don't like it!)